# Use MySQLi object based within a class

Tags: php

```
require("classes/controller.class.php");

$db = new mysqli(__DBHOST, __DBUSER, __DBPASS, __DBDATA);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$controller = new Controller;
```

Within the `Controller` class I want to use the `$db` MySQLi connection. So within a public function I used:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM colors");

var_dump($result);
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/cloud/public/teamdresser/controllers/IndexController.php on line 8
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to pass the `$db` connect first, or use global or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$db` is a global variable, you'll need to import it in your function:

```
  public function YourFunction()
  {
    global $db;

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM colors");
    ..
  }
```

Instead of doing this, you might want to consider encapsulating $db in a database class and create it as a singleton, or, arguably better, pass it to the constructor of Controller. But that remark might lead to new discussions about design, while complete books have been written about this subject. So for now, just import the global like described above. ;)

Comment: Just as I was thinking myself, thanks! Worked like a charm. I was thinking too difficult :p

Answer (score 2):

You could use a class with a singleton instance

```
class Database {

    private static $_instance;

    public static function getInstance() {

        //If the connection is not initialized, this creates it and store
        if (empty(Database::$_instance))
            Database::$_instance = new Database();
        return Database::$_instance;
    }

    private $_db;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->_db = new mysqli(__DBHOST, __DBUSER, __DBPASS, __DBDATA);

        if ($db->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
            exit();
        }
    }

    private function __destruct() {
        $this->_db->close();
    }

    public function query($query) {
        return $this->_db->query($query);
    }

}
```

You called in this manner

```
$result = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM colors");
```

You have created a connection and executed with calling a function. Once the script is terminated, the connection will be autorealeased by the destructor.

This should be only a start point. You could create all functionality that you want (e.g. escape parameters, insert, update, delete, and so on...)

Comment: Thanks Ruben for the addition!